# javascript - find last character of type in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, text, replace

I got a few names of automatically generated folders on a site.

They are named like this:

```
"folder_photos_today_1"
"folder_photos_yesterday_2"
"folder_photos_future_3"
...
"folder_potos_more_11"
```

The number at the end of each name is an ID for the folder, thats generated by a Plugin.

Now I'd like to display these folder-names like:

```
"folder photos today"
"folder photos yesterday"
```

Converting the names with javascript (pureJS or jQuery, doesn't matter) I thought about finding the last `_` in the name and deleting it and everything after it. Then search for other `_` and replace them with whitespaces.

The problem I have:
**How do I find the last character of one type** (the last `_`) **with JS?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lastIndexOf()` is what you want:

```
var index = "folder_photos_future_3".lastIndexOf('_');  // returns 20
```

You can then substring and replace your `_` with spaces.

You could also `split()` your string and discard the last value:

```
var words = "folder_photos_future_3".split('_');
words.pop();
words.join(' '); // "folder photos future"
```

Comment: Both solutions do exactly what I need and I do understand what's going on, great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be this oneliner simpler?

```
"folder_photos_today_12".replace(/_[0-9]+/g,"").replace(/_/g," ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sf2p4yua/

Here are some explanations:

```
.replace(/_[0-9]+/g,"")
```

replaces the combination of underscore and more that one digit after, so you'll have this string `folder_photos_today`.

```
.replace(/_/g," ")
```

replaces all underscores inside the string: `folder photos today`.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, too. But I have to say I'd like to know whats happening in the `replace` bracets. That character combinations are new to me. (I'm no JS pro)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this plunker link will help you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/V1hFEt37GzVq7AYUVUMa?p=preview

```
var splitFunction = function(){

var arr = ["folder_photos_today_1",
"folder_photos_yesterday_2",
"folder_photos_future_3",
"folder_photos_four_4",
"folder_photos_five_5",
"folder_photos_six_6",
"folder_photos_seven_7",
"folder_photos_eight_8",
"folder_photos_nine_9",
"folder_photos_ten_10",
"folder_potos_more_11"];

var res = [];

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "<b>RESULT : </b><br/>"
for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
  res[i] = arr[i].substr(0,arr[i].lastIndexOf('_'));
 res[i] = res[i].replace(/_/g, ' ');
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += res[i] + '<br/>';
}

}
```